# Working with tree like structures in Ember

Tags: ember.js, tree

I'm mostly understand Ember basics (or think so) related to routes, templates, controllers, it's easy to use on simple examples, but I don't know good approach how to work with tree-like structures.

Here is basic example. Say I want to show 2 lists of todo item (incomplete and completed):

```
Incomplete

 1. Todo1
 2. Todo2

Complete

 1. TodoDone1
 2. TodoDone2
```

I know 2 approaches how to implement it in Ember

1) Use nesting of routes and show these lists in separate templates, separate models:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('todo', function() {
        this.route('todocompleted');
    });
});
```

2) Use of computer properties, which filter one model and return lists for showing in one template

```
App.TodoController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    todoIncoplete: function() {
        // filter model and return list
    }.property('model.@each'),
    todoComplete: function() {
        // filter model and return list
    }.property('model.@each'),
});
```

Is it correct implementations? or can you give me any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ember provided inbuilt methods,helpers in your projects.In your case using `each` helper in template will be the best ember coding practices.

`App = Ember.Application.create({});`

```
App.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    incomplete : ['Todo1','Todo2'],
    completed : ['TodoDone1','TodoDone2']
});
```

**Handlebars template code:**

```
Incomplete:
<ol>
 {{#each task in incomplete}}
   <li>{{task}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ol>  
Complete:
<ol>
 {{#each task in completed}}
   <li>{{task}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ol>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/AhIfUhE/1/edit) is a working jsbin example.